# Php chart pchart library linux windows difference

Tags: php, pchart

Hi i am trying to use pchart library but i am getting some weird results in CentOS vps different from my windows server machine.

the code is a sample and basic one like

```
 /*
 Naked: Naked and easy!

 */


 // Standard inclusions   

 include("pChart/pData.class");

 include("pChart/pChart.class");


 // Dataset definition 

 $DataSet = new pData;

 $DataSet->AddPoint(array(1,4,3,2,3,3,2,1,0,7,4,3,2,3,3,5,1,0,7));

 $DataSet->AddSerie();

$DataSet->SetSerieName("Sample data","Serie1");


// Initialise the graph

$Test = new pChart(700,230);

 $Test->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",10);

$Test->setGraphArea(40,30,680,200);

$Test->drawGraphArea(252,252,252,TRUE);




$Test->drawScale($DataSet->GetData(),$DataSet->GetDataDescription(),SCALE_NORMAL,150,150,150,TRUE,0,2);

$Test->drawGrid(4,TRUE,230,230,230,70);


// Draw the line graph

$Test->drawLineGraph($DataSet->GetData(),$DataSet->GetDataDescription());


$Test->drawPlotGraph($DataSet->GetData(),$DataSet->GetDataDescription(),3,2,255,255,255);


// Finish the graph

$Test->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",8);

$Test->drawLegend(45,35,$DataSet->GetDataDescription(),255,255,255);

$Test->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",10);

$Test->drawTitle(60,22,"My pretty graph",50,50,50,585);

$Test->Render("Naked.png");

?>
```

The resulting image in windows is [image: Win]

and the result in CentOS VPS of that same code is [image: Lix]

I think it might have to do with versions of php_gd2.dll or something.
This is the version of pchart i am using [version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pchart/files/pchart/pChart%201.27%20-%20beta/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a font issue, as the only difference that I can see is that it is missing its text. Without a CentOS install, I can't test this out, though I would experiment with a simple graph using the `drawTitle($X,$Y,$Text,$Format="")` function, and some different fonts in CentOS.